# HAProxy - Proxy to sites behind an internal ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, amazon-alb

I currently have an internal ALB (Not accessible to the world) with some microservices running. I now want the world to access certain microservices.

I would like to place a HAProxy cluster in front of my internal ALB that proxies the requests through it.

```
backend microservices
   reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /microservice/(.*) \1\ /\2
```

The above piece of config catches all the requests coming from hostnames that contain the word microservice. That seems to work. But how can I proxy them?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at some guides for HAProxy configuration files, it won't happen without it.

And once you do it, I think you should use a setup like this:

- define haproxy ACLs

`acl microservices_acl hdr_beg(host) -i microservices   use_backend microsservices_backend if microservices_acl`

- backend

`backend microservices_backend
      balance source
      hash-type consistent
      option httpclose
      server <FQDN of the server you need to proxy to> <ip address of that server>:80 check`

There are sample `haproxy` configurations all over the Internet, check them!

Comment: And, don't forget that you need to enable and use the HAProxy asynchronous DNS `resolver` on each `server` line in the config, so that HAProxy can keep the IP address of the balancer current.  They are not static.